# Create a discord bot that allows a specific word in a text channel and deleted any other words

Tags: discord, discord.js

I’m trying to create a discord bot that only allows you to type a certain word in a text channel and then deletes any other words that don’t match that desired word. I have this message event that I found that works but I’m trying to expand upon it to include uppercase of the word and other forms as well.

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if(message.content !=      "upgrade") return message.delete()
```

});

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that would be to first trim all the space in the front and end of the content by using `message.content.trim()` but this wouldn't remove any spaces in the middle of the content. If you want to remove all the spaces in the middle as well, you can just use RegEx to replace all the spaces by using `message.content.replace(/ /g, '')`. Then you can use `.toLowerCase()` to turn all the uppercase characters to lowercase. Then finally you can just use `message.content.includes('your-word')` to check if the message content has the word. Your code might look like this:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.content.replace(/ /g, '').toLowerCase().includes('your-word')) {
        // Do something
    }
})
```

**Revised Method**

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.content.replace(/ /g, '').toLowerCase() === 'your-word') {
        // Do something
    }
})
```

**Another Way**

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
    const args = message.content.toLowerCase().split(' ')
    let hasUpgrade = true
    args.forEach(word => {
        if (word !== 'upgrade') hasUpgrade = false
    })
    if (!hasUpgrade) return message.delete()
})
```

Comment: That’s exactly what I’m looking for. Awesome, thank you!

Comment: Actually, I think you can remove the `.trim()` function since the `.replace()` function will catch it. I edited the answer accordingly

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working correctly. My code looks as follows:

client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.content.replace(/ /g, '').toLowerCase().includes(upgrade)) return message.delete()
});

Comment: Why? What's the behaviour you are getting?

Comment: I think it might be because you are using the word `upgrade` in the `.includes()` function without giving single-quotes or double-quotes

Comment: So i actually have it working now, but I want it to work opposite haha. I want it to only accept "upgrade" and delete the other words. Can't I just make it a "not include" function in this case? not sure what the syntax for that would be. 

So basically just want to turn the "include" into a "not include".

Comment: In that case, you can just add an exclamation mark at the first like this => `if (!message.content.replace(/ /g), '')`

Comment: So found a loophole with that solution..... As long as I include "upgrade" in any sentence it lets the whole sentence through.

Comment: Then instead of using `.replace()`, you can just check if the message content is equal to your word. You can just add this to the end of the if check => `message.content === 'your-word'`

Comment: Well I want it to still be able to pick up uppercase, spaces, and any other way of typing “upgrade” someone may do. Wouldn’t that change make it have to equal “upgrade” exactly?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Instead of removing the `.replace()` function, you have to remove the `.includes()`. After removing it, you just have to add the check I told now in place of the `.includes()`. That way, the message content will be turned to lowercase, it wouldn't have any spaces and then if the remaining content is exactly `upgrade`, then it would let it go

Comment: Yup that worked beautifully. The last part that I can’t figure out it getting it to accept “upgrade upgrade”. If I type the word twice it doesn’t recognize it and deletes it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I added another way to the answer